# Chrome Remote Interface: How to Wait Until a New Page Loads

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, interface

Basically I want to navigate to google.com, print the title “Google”, then click on the about button, and print the title “About Us | Google”.

The issue is it doesn’t wait for the about page to load, and it instead prints “Google” again.

If I connect to the remote debugger then it’s clearly clicking and navigating to the about page correctly.

```
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');

/**
 * Launches a debugging instance of Chrome.
 * @param {boolean=} headless True (default) launches Chrome in headless mode.
 *     False launches a full version of Chrome.
 * @return {Promise<ChromeLauncher>}
 */
function launchChrome(headless=true) {
  return chromeLauncher.launch({
    port: 9222,
    chromeFlags: [
      '--disable-gpu',
      headless ? '--headless' : ''
    ]
  });
}

(async function() {

const chrome = await launchChrome();
const protocol = await CDP({port: chrome.port});

const {Page, Runtime} = protocol;
await Promise.all([Page.enable(), Runtime.enable()]);

const url = "https://www.google.com/";

Page.navigate({url: url});

// Wait for window.onload before doing stuff.
Page.loadEventFired(async () => {
  const result1 = await Runtime.evaluate({expression: "document.querySelector('title').textContent"});
  // Prints "Google"
  console.log('Title of page: ' + result1.result.value);

  // Navigate to the About page
  const result2 = await Runtime.evaluate({expression: "document.querySelector('#fsl a:nth-child(3)').click()"});

  const result3 = await Runtime.evaluate({expression: "document.querySelector('title').textContent"});
  // This should have printed "About Us | Google" but instead printed "Google"
  console.log('Title of page: ' + result3.result.value);

  protocol.close();
});

})();
```

Answer (score 4):

I was just looking at the flow incorrectly. Page.loadEventFired gets called after every new page gets loaded. So you change the code to this type of format and it works great.

```
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');

/**
 * Launches a debugging instance of Chrome.
 * @param {boolean=} headless True (default) launches Chrome in headless mode.
 *     False launches a full version of Chrome.
 * @return {Promise<ChromeLauncher>}
 */
function launchChrome(headless=true) {
  return chromeLauncher.launch({
    port: 9222,
    chromeFlags: [
      '--disable-gpu',
      headless ? '--headless' : ''
    ]
  });
}

(async function() {

const chrome = await launchChrome();
const protocol = await CDP({port: chrome.port});

const {Page, Runtime} = protocol;
await Promise.all([Page.enable(), Runtime.enable()]);

const url = "https://www.google.com/";

Page.navigate({url: url});

// Create a value to track which page we are on
let pageNum = 0;

// Wait for window.onload before doing stuff.
Page.loadEventFired(async () => {

  if (pageNum === 0) {
    const result1 = await Runtime.evaluate({expression: "document.querySelector('title').textContent"});

    // Prints "Google"
    console.log('Title of page: ' + result1.result.value);

    // Navigate to the About page
    const result2 = await Runtime.evaluate({expression: "document.querySelector('#fsl a:nth-child(3)').click()"});
    pageNum = 1;

  } else if (pageNum === 1) {
    const result3 = await Runtime.evaluate({expression: "document.querySelector('title').textContent"});

    // Prints "About Us | Google"
    console.log('Title of page: ' + result3.result.value);

    protocol.close();
  }

});

})();
```